# Parse String representation value into Java class type

Tags: java

I have a webservice which responds with "dynamic fields" as depending on the object the amount of fields may vary and be only on that object.

Description looks like this

```
<field name="ISSUER" code="ISSUER_USER">test123</field> // 1
<field name="START" code="INSURANCE_PERIOD_START">2015-05-19</field> // 2
<field name="NATURAL DISASTER" code="MOD_NATURAL_DISASTER">600.00</field>
<field name="FIRE" code="MOD_FIRE">600.00</field> // 3
<field name="VANDALISM" code="MOD_VANDALISM">600.00</field>
<field name="THEFT" code="MOD_THEFT">600.00</field>
```

As the values are all Strings, I need to be able to create an abstraction for the field type that can store all these values.

Now the commented field **1** is a String type, that's fine, normal Strings are handeled as they are, but **2**, is a date representation and I need to convert it to other pattern in front end, **3** is a money amount field, which needs to become BigDecimal for example.

There are loads of fields like that in different lists, all type of `field`.

I would like to have an class `FieldData` which has variables `String name;` and value is generic depending on the value parsed `Class<?> value` or something? I don't know. Or it could just be String as well for the value and do the parsing before assigning so the end representation can be in String format for all the values.

**My question is:** How should I write the parser that would be able to determine if the field is supposed to be converted if it's decimal, parsed to another date format if it's date, or for other Strings just assign the current value.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `XML` parser should help.

Comment: I am already unmarshalling this into a java class

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to update the web service to provide type attribute for the field tag. Failing which you can use a set of regular expressions trying to match each one of them from most-specific to most-generic. So you try to parse date, if it fails parse it for integer, if it fails parse it for double finally if all of them fail take it as a string value.

Comment: I raised a question in regards of changing the service, hopefully they can do it. Else guess the fail ladder has to do it.